# How can I use a nested attribute's translation in a label so I only maintain one translation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Very new to i18n so forgive if this is simple, but I could not find the question answered anywhere.

I have *n* models that `belong_to: location`

I want to assign a translation to `location` such that when parent objects display their child `location` the translation appears.

Models

```
class Model1 < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: location
class Model2 < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: location
.
.
.
class ModelN < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: location

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many: model1s
  has_many: model2s
  has_many: modelNs
```

Views
Model1 create view

```
<%= form_with(model: model1, local: true) do |form| %>
.
.        
   <td><%= form.label :location %></td>
   <td><%= form.select(:location_id, @location_options) %></td>
```

Model2 create view

```
<%= form_with(model: model2, local: true) do |form| %>
.
.        
   <td><%= form.label :location %></td>
   <td><%= form.select(:location_id, @location_options) %></td>
```

I tried both assigning a global label, as well as the model name. Neither worked.

fr.yml

```
fr:
  helpers:
    label:
      location: 'Emplacement'
  activerecord:
    models:
      location:
        one: 'Emplacement'
        other: 'Emplacements'
```

When I assigned a translation to the `Create` submit helper, it applied globally (without even having to precede with `t.(...)`.  I was hoping this would work similarly with `form.label` but alas, it does not.  Is there a way to globally assign a translation for labels which represent the names of nested objects?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a common block in YAML:

```yaml
fr:
  common: &common_values
    location:
      one: 'Emplacement'
      other: 'Emplacements'

  activerecord:
    models:
      model1:
        <<: *common_values
        name: 'Model 1'
      model2:
        <<: *common_values
        name: 'Model 2'
```